# How can i view the SQL Agent in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-studio

I have installed Azure Data Studio and the extension SQL Agent. I have also installed the Admin package extension as it seems to be under that.

It does not appear when i click on Manage for the connected database.

How can i get it to appear ?

Answer (score 1):

I installed Azure data studio and  sql server agent in Azure data studio using extension menu.
Image for reference:

[image]

After connection of Sql Server without clicking manage automatically Sql agent is appear in my case.
Image for reference:

[image]

1. If the Login account connecting to Azure data studio is not a part of SysAdmin role in SQL Server, then SQL Server Agent would not be visible to check this run below query in Azure data studio

```
Select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('Sysadmin')
```

If a value is zero, then you are not a Sysadmin and hence you can’t see SQL Server Agent.

I run the above query I got as

[image]

2. Another possible reason would be that SQL Server in not an edition which supports SQL Server Agent. Typically, SQL Server Express edition could be another cause.

To verify, you can run below query in Azure data studio

```
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
```

I run above query in my system I got as

If the output is “Express” or “Express Edition with Advanced Services”, then you would not see SQL Server Agent node in Azure data studio.

[image]

Kindly check above properties of your sql server.

Comment: the Edition is SQL Azure, but the Select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('Sysadmin') returns 0 , so the user is not a sysadmin and to get the sysadmin pwd , need to talk to IT to get it

Comment: is there any other way of checking jobs that have run on the server via a select  by Querying Azure SQL Server Agent Job History Information /Data

Comment: Try this query SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory;

Comment: gives error : Reference to database and/or server name in 'msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: it is a SQL Azure SQL Server 12.0.2000.8

Comment: So i have the admin user logged in and stil cant see the Server Agent

Comment: Does the Select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('Sysadmin') returns 0 or 1?